# How to get chapter title in header the same color when chapter title itself is in multiple fonts with different colors?

Tags: color, header-footer, titlesec

Assume I need to sandwich English words in chapter titles which are mainly in Burmese. I want those sandwiched English words in red color. However I want to have all the headers text only in gray keeping the same font in the original chapter titles. How can I achieve that? Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside, openright]{book}
\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "my_MM"  %Myanmar line and character breaks
\XeTeXinterwordspaceshaping = 2

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newfontfamily{\ubuntumono}{Fira Mono}[Script=Latin]% replace Fira with Ubuntu
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textubuntumono}{\ubuntumono}

\newcommand{\class}{\myCodePar{class}}
\newcommand{\turnLeft}{\myCodePar{turnLeft}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myCodePar}{om}{%
  % #1 = optional color, #2 = text
  \textubuntumono{\IfValueT{#1}{\addfontfeatures{Color=#1}}#2}%
}

\definecolor{myParColor}{HTML}{4E4D4D}
\definecolor{myParColor1}{rgb}{1,0,0}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\Huge}{\color{blue}\thechapter}{10pt}{\color{blue}}
    {\filcenter} 

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
    % header မှာ အခန်း ၁ ကို boldfont နဲ့ မစောင်းပဲပေါ်အောင် 
    \markboth{{\color{gray}\bfseries{\chaptername\ \thechapter~~~}}% 
        % chapter title ကို italic နဲ့ ပေါ်အောင် 
        {\color{gray}\bfseries{#1}}}{}}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Burmese Txt \myCodePar[red]{Some Eng Txt} Burmese Txt}
\newpage
sometext
\newpage
sometext

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot to your question?

Comment: @MS-SPO, sure. I've added screenshots.

Comment: This is one way  `\chapter[Burmese Txt Some Eng Txt Burmese Txt]{Burmese Txt \myCodePar[red]{Some Eng Txt} Burmese Txt}`.  Put into `[] ` what goes to the header.

Comment: So you are using the optional [subtitel] for this purpose to "remove" colors, right? (@PyiSoe See e.g. here https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/html/sectionunits.html , and follow the chapter-link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make `\myCodePar` do nothing inside the header.

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\NotmyCodePar}{om}{#2}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
    % header မှာ အခန်း ၁ ကို boldfont နဲ့ မစောင်းပဲပေါ်အောင် 
    \markboth{{\color{gray}\bfseries{\chaptername\ \thechapter~~~}}% 
        % chapter title ကို italic နဲ့ ပေါ်အောင် 
        {\color{gray}\bfseries{\let\myCodePar\NotmyCodePar#1}}}{}}
```

[image]

Comment: @Oostrum thanks for the help. I noticed your method change the font as well, not just the color. Is it possible to just change the color of the font in the header retaining the font type.

Comment: You could copy the font from `\myCodePar` into `\NotmyCodePar` if you want to retain that.

Comment: Thank! I just have tested and it produced the result I need.